# How do I implement equality for an abstract base class?

Tags: c#, abstract-class, iequatable

I'm following the [MSDN guidance for value equality](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd183755.aspx), and I found a case that the documentation didn't cover, equality for a base class.

### A little background:

I'm working on a Mahjong game (4-player, not matching), and I'm working on defining the tiles. Tiles can be broken into two groups: suits, which have a number associated with them (and can be put together in sequences, like 2-3-4) and honor tiles, which have no number.

### Here's what I have so far:

```cs
public enum MahjongSuitType
{
    Bamboo = 1,
    Character,
    Dot
}

public enum MahjongSuitNumber
{
    One = 1,
    Two,
    Three,
    Four,
    Five,
    Six,
    Seven,
    Eight,
    Nine
}

public enum MahjongHonorType
{
    GreenDragon = 1,
    RedDragon,
    WhiteDragon,
    EastWind,
    SouthWind,
    WestWind,
    NorthWind
}

public abstract class MahjongTile
{

}

public class MahjongSuitTile : MahjongTile, IEquatable<MahjongTile>
{
    public MahjongSuitType SuitType { get; private set; }
    public MahjongSuitNumber SuitNumber { get; private set; }
    public bool IsRedBonus { get; private set; }  //this has no bearing on equality

    public MahjongSuitTile(MahjongSuitType suitType, 
                           MahjongSuitNumber suitNumber, 
                           bool isRedBonus = false)
    {
        this.SuitType = suitType;
        this.SuitNumber = suitNumber;
        this.IsRedBonus = isRedBonus;
    }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        return this.Equals(obj as MahjongTile);
    }

    public bool Equals(MahjongTile other)
    {
        if (Object.ReferenceEquals(other, null))
            return false;
        if (Object.ReferenceEquals(other, this))
            return true;

        MahjongSuitTile otherSuitTile = other as MahjongSuitTile;
        if (Object.ReferenceEquals(otherSuitTile, null))
            return false;

        return (this.SuitType == otherSuitTile.SuitType) && 
               (this.SuitNumber == otherSuitTile.SuitNumber);
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return this.SuitType.GetHashCode() ^ this.SuitNumber.GetHashCode();
    }

}

public class MahjongHonorTile : MahjongTile, IEquatable<MahjongTile>
{
    public MahjongHonorType HonorType { get; private set; }

    public MahjongHonorTile(MahjongHonorType honorType)
    {
        this.HonorType = HonorType;
    }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        return this.Equals(obj as MahjongTile);
    }

    public bool Equals(MahjongTile other)
    {
        if (Object.ReferenceEquals(other, null))
            return false;
        if (Object.ReferenceEquals(other, this))
            return true;

        MahjongHonorTile otherHonorTile = other as MahjongHonorTile;
        if (Object.ReferenceEquals(otherHonorTile, null))
            return false;

        return this.HonorType == otherHonorTile.HonorType;
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return this.HonorType.GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

For the majority of the code, I'd like to refer to the tiles via the base class, something like:

```cs
List<MahjongTile> hand = new List<MahjongTile>() { ... };

HashSet<MahjongTile> dragonTiles = new HashSet()
{
    new MahjongHonorTile(MahjongHonorType.GreenDragon),
    new MahjongHonorTile(MahjongHonorType.RedDragon),
    new MahjongHonorTile(MahjongHonorType.WhiteDragon)
}

IEnumerable<MahjongTile> dragonTilesInHand = hand.Where(t => dragonTiles.Contains(t));
```

My Question: how should I define equality in the `MahjongTile` base class?

Comment: It looks like question you need to answer yourself first how do you want it to behave, and than (if needed) ask to help with implementation. I personally recommend to explicitly specify comparers in `Where` and similar functions - if you want to do searches on partial values....

Answer (score 0):

Since [Object.Equals](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bsc2ak47.aspx) is virtual, the subclasses implementation override the method. No further code is needed.